# If net force is 0, why does elongation occur in a rod?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, stress-strain

I was taught that stress is the restoring force per unit area (let us assume a rod). This stress is developed on order to resist the motion of the rod. My questions are as follows :

1. If the rod is subjected to equal and opposite forces why is stress developed as the rod has 0 net force acting on it

My reasoning : the rod can be assumed to be made of differentially small rod elements in a line. When the elements on the edges are pulled a tension force is generated to oppose it's motion.

2. Why does elongation occur  if the net force is 0 (forces applied on the ends of the rod) ? In order for elongation to occur there must be some net force on the elements on the edges for them to start elongation but since tension is generated as soon as we apply equal and opposite external forces, there won't be any force imbalance.

My reasoning: The forces are equal and the net force is 0. The rod is expanding but it's center of mass is 0.

I think I'm confusing elongation and net acceleration. Please let me know the errors in my reasoning

Comment: I am not able to understand why is net force 0 on the rod? Is it because it's massless?

Comment: I would say thinking of tiny differential sections of the rod is good way to go about it, such that the tension at each side cancel.

Comment: @Ohw the rod is being pulled by equal and opposite forces on the ends.

Answer (score 3):

> I think I'm confusing elongation and net acceleration. Please let me
> know the errors in my reasoning

When the force is initially applied (at $t=0$) the rod acts very much as a spring but not necessarily a 'perfect', Hookean spring where $F=kx$, but more like:

$$F(x)=k(x)x$$

[image: Force of x]

During a brief period of time the rod is being elongated from $x=0$ to $x$. During that period there was acceleration **until the restoring force exerted by the rod equals the externally exerted force** $F_{ext}$ and:
$$F_{ext}=k(x)x$$

There's now no net force and **no more acceleration** but during that initial acceleration the net force was:

$$F_{net}=F_{ext}-F(x)$$

Comment: But the elongation still continues even after the restoring force becomes equal to the applied (external) force. Right? Also, does the center of mass move during elongation ?

Comment: No, the elongation STOPS when the restoring force becomes equal to the applied (external) force. But **during** elongation the CoG does move, that is correct.

Comment: If the CoG moves doesn't that mean that we have deformed as well as moved the rod. If the net force is 0 how can there be motion (assuming the rod to be at rest initially)

Comment: Sorry, I was going by a rod that was clamped on one side. If equally clamped on both sides the CoG does of course not move (symmetry).

Comment: Also I don't think that the elongation stops when the restoring force becomes equal as there is still stress in the rod.

Comment: I not forgot :-) +1.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote! *[...] as there is still stress in the rod* We need to look at the infinitesimal level for that.

Comment: Take a REAL, Hookean spring and hang a weight $mg$ from it. There's stress but does elongation still increase after $F=kx=mg$? No!

Answer (score 2):

*"I was taught that stress is the restoring force per unit area (let us assume a rod). This stress is developed on order to resist the motion of the rod."*

I'm not sure this framework is very useful if it's leading you to contradictions or paradoxes. I think of a stress state as arising through sets of balanced forces: 2 forces for normal stress, 4 forces for shear stress:

[image][image]

[image][image]

(Images from [my site](http://john.maloney.org/Structural/generalized%20Hooke%27s%20Law.htm))

Broadly, we define stress this way (i.e., we subtract unbalanced forces that would tend to make a body accelerate) because we want to focus on elasticity and ignore dynamics. You *want* there to be zero net force and zero net moment on an object before you start your static stress/strain analysis. This way, you'll never conflate elongation and acceleration because they've been decoupled.

One you have your balanced sets of forces, you can determine the stresses (normal and shear, in all three axes) from the associated force/area pairs and then determine the strain.

Comment: can I think of stress as a resistance to elongation ?

Comment: The resistance to elongation is the stiffness (specifically, the tensile stiffness), which is different from stress.

Answer (score 1):

When Newton wrote that $F=ma$, there was another guy at Cambridge, Mr Hooke that wrote that $F=kx$.

In a way Newton prevails and his equation is now the definition of force. But force as the net force.

If this force is done by pulling an object with a spring, it is expected that $kx = ma$. If that correspondence is not exact, we say that the spring is not perfectly linear elastic, and $F \approx kx$ for that spring.

Hooke's concept of force is not related to movement, so a rod can be static, and subject to a force $F$ at both ends. Or it can be accelerated with the force $F$ only at one of the ends. Both ways: $F=kx$.

Comment: But how can the rod be compared to a spring ? Doesn't a rod/string deform under a constant force (at least until the Young' Modulus equation holds ) unlike a spring on which the external force needs to be increased with linear displacement.

Answer (score 1):

If you suddenly apply a substantial force to the ends of a rod, the same thing will happen as if you apply a force to a spring having mass:  there will be oscillations (i.e., acceleration), even if Young's modulus is perfectly constant.  But the oscillations will die out with time (as a result of small damping effects that are present). If you gradually apply a force to a rod, the inertial effects will be substantially less, and the main thing that you will get is a rod under static tension.

In a rod under static tension, the internal molecular structure of the solid rod will experience deformation due to the applied loading, just the same as when you apply tension to a spring with equal forces at its ends.

Answer (score 0):

Stress takes into account the restoring force only. And restoring force is the internal force produced by the body. It's the next external force that is zero. But since internal force is not zero, there would be a stress and thus a corresponding elongation. The body won't have acceleration since net external force is zero.